# Trimming videos with 'ffmpeg and ffprobe'

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffprobe

I am working on an ETL process, and I'm now in the final stage of preprocessing my videos. I used the script below (reference: @FarisHijazi) to first auto detected black-screen frames using ffprobe and trim them out using ffmpeg.

The script worked for me but the problems are:

1. It cut off all other good frames together with the first bad frames. e.g. if gBgBgBgB represents a sequence of good and BAD frames for 5sec each, the script only returned the first g(5sec) and cut off the other BgBgBgB after it. I want to have only g g g g where all B B B B has been removed
2. I also want to detect other colors aside black-screen e.g. green-screen or red-screen or blurry part of video
3. Script doesn't work if video has no audio in it.

```
import argparse
import os
import shlex
import subprocess

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    __doc__, formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
)
parser.add_argument("input", type=str, help="input video file")
parser.add_argument(
    "--invert",
    action="store_true",
    help="remove nonblack instead of removing black",
)
args = parser.parse_args()

##FIXME: sadly you must chdir so that the ffprobe command will work
os.chdir(os.path.split(args.input)[0])
args.input = os.path.split(args.input)[1]

spl = args.input.split(".")
outpath = (
    ".".join(spl[:-1])
    + "."
    + ("invert" if args.invert else "")
    + "out."
    + spl[-1]
)


def delete_back2back(l):
    from itertools import groupby

    return [x[0] for x in groupby(l)]


def construct_ffmpeg_trim_cmd(timepairs, inpath, outpath):
    cmd = f'ffmpeg -i "{inpath}" -y -r 20 -filter_complex '
    cmd += '"'
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(timepairs):
        cmd += (
            f"[0:v]trim=start={start}:end={end},setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=yuv420p[{i}v]; "
            + f"[0:a]atrim=start={start}:end={end},asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[{i}a]; "
        )
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(timepairs):
        cmd += f"[{i}v][{i}a]"
    cmd += f"concat=n={len(timepairs)}:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"
    cmd += '"'
    cmd += f' -map [outv] -map [outa] "{outpath}"'
    return cmd


def get_blackdetect(inpath, invert=False):
    ffprobe_cmd = f'ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie={inpath},blackdetect[out0]" -show_entries tags=lavfi.black_start,lavfi.black_end -of default=nw=1 -v quiet'
    print("ffprobe_cmd:", ffprobe_cmd)
    lines = (
        subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(ffprobe_cmd))
        .decode("utf-8")
        .split("\n")
    )
    times = [
        float(x.split("=")[1].strip()) for x in delete_back2back(lines) if x
    ]
    assert len(times), "no black scene detected"

    if not invert:
        times = [0] + times[:-1]
    timepairs = [
        (times[i], times[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(times) // 2, 2)
    ]
    return timepairs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    timepairs = get_blackdetect(args.input, invert=args.invert)
    cmd = construct_ffmpeg_trim_cmd(timepairs, args.input, outpath)

    print(cmd)
    os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: #3 is easy. Your filtergraph has audio filters in it, which expects `0:a` stream. If there is no audio stream, your fg fails. You need to check the presence of audio stream when you create the fg.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i make the audio optional, such that the script will also work on it even if there is no audio involved

Comment: From ffmpeg-world, the easiest thing to do is to call `ffprobe -of json INPUT` to get media info. Pipe stdout to python and use `json.load` to retrieve the info. You can peek into my `ffmpegio` project (`probe.py`) on GitHub, but it's there are a bunch of other resources out there.